# Hibernate. Delete unused entry

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a table looks which like this:

```
ID  USER_NAME ROOM_ID
 1  user1   13
 2  user2   11  
 3  user3   null
 4  user4   4   
 5  user5   2
```

And Room table

```
ID  ROOM_NAME SQUARE
13  room1   17
 4  room2   42  
 2  room3   26
11  room4   37  
 5  room5   28
```

In my application i can change User's ROOM_ID, for example, for Null. And after this, i'll have a one "Unused" room (There's no user in this room).

So, the question is: **How can i delete this room automaticly using Hibernate?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is an automatic way, but wouldn't it suffice to instead of setting the room to null to delete the entry right away?

Comment: @Tom But i can set the room to another room, not only to null. And after this, i need to delete this unused room, somehow.

Comment: what you are going to do is "wrong" from back end design perspective, rooms are something that can exist even without having a user. if you believe that  it is right to remove the room, technically there shouldn't be entity called "Room". it should be an embedable in the User entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a trigger for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_room()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM ROOMS WHERE (OLD.ROOM_ID = ID)
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$


CREATE TRIGGER delete_room_changed
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON USERS
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_room()
```

that way when you update any user the assigned room is deleted

Answer (score -1):

Try this code - see the comments for details:

```
Session session = null;
if(session == null) {
    initTransaction();
}

Room room = (Room) session.createCriteria(UserRoomTable.class); // First table Pojo class name
room.add(Restrictions.isNull("roomId"));
session.delete(room); // This deletes the unused entry
```